# Wait a time before do action without stop server

Tags: java, time, minecraft, wait

I'm working on a bedwars plugin for minecraft server, everythings work but at the starting i want a 5sec timer before starting the game and show a title on the game, i worked on this code :

```
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        sendtitle("4");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        sendtitle("3");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        sendtitle("2");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        sendtitle("1");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        sendtitle("SusyBaka");
```

But i completly pausing the server, i tried to use multi thread but the title don't apear, can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should NOT use `Thread.sleep()` or something like that on spigot-server because such as you said, it stop the FULL server (and it can make player timed out)

To make a timer, use this :

```java
public int count = 5;
public BukkitTask task;

public void method() {
   task = Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().runTaskTimer(MyPlugin.getInstance(), () -> {
      if(count == 0) {
         task.cancel();
         sendtitle("SusyBaka");
      } else {
         count--;
         sendtitle("Start in " + count + " seconds");
      }
   }, 20, 20); // 20 ticks = 1 second
}
```